# Why does Kim call the police?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

Why did William "Bill" Kim call the police in *Prison Break*, when it's obvious that he wanted to kill Lincoln. It makes no sense. Kim would go to jail, right?

Comment: which season does this happen

Comment: @war_Hero: It happens in last episode of second season.

Answer (score 1):

He called police because Michael was still on run from Fox River.

His plan according to me was to kill Lincoln and capture Michael.

Once arrested Michael would had been sent back to Fox River.